# nontrivial query

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I need to write a query.
have 3 tables, one main and two associated
for example :

```
main_table
id   name
--   -------------
1    example
2    example2

join_table1
id   main_table_id
--   -------------
 1     1

join_table2
id   main_table_id
--   -------------
1      2
```

if main_table_id contained in join_table1
I need to sort by join_table1.id, else if main_table_id contained in join_table2,
 
i need to sort by join_table2.id

any ideas how to make such query
main_table_id  can be either in table join_table1 or join_table2
database - SQL Server

Comment: Please show your desired results from your sample data instead of describing them with a word problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and left joins. Query will look like:

```
select ...
from main_table
left outer join join_table1 j1 on ...
left outer join join_table2 j2 on ...
order by coalesce( j1.id, j2.id )
```